# BB10 simulator magnify off

Tags: blackberry-10

In BB10 simulator, I clicked `settings>accesibility>magnify`. Then screen become larger. I closed the settings application.

Now again I opened settings application to off magnify(unmagnify). But it is not scrolling down to `accessiblity`. Please find the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Kda.png). So please let me know how to unmagnify this or else let me know how to wipe out the simulator data.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator you're using is 10.0.10 which is fairly old. Try downloading the latest version of the simulator (10.3.0) here: https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html to see if that solves the issue.